# Using doParallel with RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, doparallel

I am trying to use doParallel with RMarkdown.
The R code calls a script called report.RMD. The goal is to produce 3 html reports from the iris dataset, each one named after the species with a table in that is filtered down to that species.
The problem is that although the reports are rendered, the table doesn't get filtered to that species for example, the virginica.html document has the versicolor species listed. This appears to be a parallelisation issue because when %dopar% is changed to %do%, the html reports are produced as expected.

The wider objective is to use parallel processing with RMarkdown on a larger scale than on this example but am using the below just as an example.

The R code is:

```
library(doParallel)
library(tidyverse)

iris_list<-c("virginica","versicolor", "setosa")

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1  

cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)  
registerDoParallel(cl)  

foreach(i = 1:length(iris_list), .packages = (.packages())) %dopar% {

cat<-iris_list[i]
iris2<-iris%>%filter(Species==cat)
  
rmarkdown::render("report.RMD",
output_file = paste0(cat, ".html"))
}  

stopCluster(cl)
```

The RMD code is:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "28 September 2021"
output: html_document
---



```{r table, echo=FALSE}
iris2
````

Answer (score 1):

Found one approach here: https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/17bc21af55392f23f012f57bb2fda51c#file-do_rpt-r

```
library(doParallel)
library(tidyverse)

# Define report parameters
reports <- list(list(out="setosa.html", params=list(sp="setosa")),
             list(out="virginica.html", params=list(sp="virginica")),
             list(out="versicolor.html", params=list(sp="versicolor")))

make_report <- function(r) {
  
  require(rmarkdown)
  
  tf <- tempfile()
  dir.create(tf)
  
  rmarkdown::render(input="report.RMD",
                    output_file=r$out,
                    intermediates_dir=tf,
                    params=r$params,
                    quiet=TRUE)
  unlink(tf)
  
}

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1  
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)  
registerDoParallel(cl)  

foreach(r=reports, .combine=c) %dopar% make_report(r)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "28 September 2021"
output: html_document
params:
  sp: "default"
---

```{r}
data(iris)
iris[iris$Species == params$sp,]
````

(plus three trailing ` for the r-chunk... stack formatting is confused).

Comment: This has the same problem, when I run it as the code given, the virginica.html document has the versicolor species listed. There seems a randomness to how the dataframe is being filtered with the filename not matching the dataframe filter despite it being the same variable.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I thought it was working when I posted the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I updated my answer... unfortunately most of the code is still running on the rmarkdown side though.